# Async Await Returns Promise <pending>

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to use async / await in an express route and cant get it to work correctly. I have looked at several SO posts and it seems I'm doing it right.

Helpers:

```
module.exports = {

 facebook: function(userId, token) {
   return new Promise(resolver)
   function resolver(resolve, reject) {
      graph.get(`${userId}/feed?access_token=${token}`, function(err, res) {
         if (err) {
            if(res.paging && res.paging.next) {
              graph.get(res.paging.next, function(err2, res2) {

                var arr = []

                res.data.forEach(function(e) {
                  if (e.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
                    arr.push(e.message) 
                  } else if (e.hasOwnProperty('story')) {
                    arr.push(e.story)
                  } else {
                    console.log('something is not here')
                  }
                }) 

                res2.data.forEach(function(e) {
                  if (e.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
                  arr.push(e.message) 
                  } else if (e.hasOwnProperty('story')) {
                    arr.push(e.story)
                  } else {
                    console.log('something is not here')
                  }
                })
                console.log(arr)
                resolve(arr.toString())

              })

            }
         } 
      })
   }      

  },
  twitter: function(twittername) {
    return new Promise(resolver) 
    function resolver(resolve, reject) {
      T.get('search/tweets', { q: `from:${twittername}`, count: 500 }, function(err, data, response) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          data.statuses.forEach(function(e) {
          arr.push(e.text)
        })

      }
      resolve(arr.toString())
    })

    }

    console.log(arr)
     return arr.toString()
},
personalityInsights: function (fullString) { 
  console.log('fullString', fullString)
  personality_insights.profile({
      text: fullString,
      consumption_preferences: true
    },
    function (err, response) {
      if (err) {console.log(err)}
      else console.log(response)
    });
  }
}
```

Inside Route.js

```
 async function main() {
    try {
       facebookR = await helpers.facebook(userId, accessToken)
       twitterR = await helpers.twitter(twittername)
       return await helpers.personalityInsights(`${facebookR} ${twitterR}`)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('err main', e)
    }
  }

 main()
```

I originally had an issue with using callbacks in my helpers and converted them to promises because I learned Async functions return promises. But with this code, I still cant return the values I want. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: *"But with this code, I still cant return the values I want."* Which value do you want to return from where? As you said, `async` functions return promises.

Comment: ``helpers.personalityInsights(${facebookR} ${twitterR})`` is ultimately what I want to return

The idea is I'm using async await to pass values in a specific order then the last awaited function returns the final result.

Comment: And you are wondering why `main` returns a pending promise instead? Again, you said it yourself: `async` functions return promises. That promise will eventually resolve to whatever `helpers.personalityInsights(`${facebookR} ${twitterR}`)` resolves to. You extract the value of a promise, you have to pass a callback via `.then`, i.e. `main().then(result => console.log(result))`.

Comment: those logs dont fire for whatever reason

Comment: Please always end your statements with `;`..., and declare your variables! You could get scary information leaking with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> personalityInsights: function (fullString) { 
>   console.log('fullString', fullString)
>   personality_insights.profile({
>       text: fullString,
>       consumption_preferences: true
>     },
>     function (err, response) {
>       if (err) {console.log(err)}
>       else console.log(response)
>     });
>   }
> ```

You should be returning some values from `personalityInsights` function.